# Submitting form results with error: The current path, home/insert, didn't match any of these

Tags: django, django-views

When I click on submit button is shows me this error:

> Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> ^admin/
>
> ^home/$
>
> ^insert/$ 
>   [name='insert']
>
> The current path, home/insert, didn't match any of these.

views.py:

```
def insert_page(request):
    name1 = request.GET['NAME']
    email1 = request.GET['EMAIL']
    message1 = request.GET['MSG']
    data = Feedback(name = name1,email = email1 , message =message1)
    data.save()
    return HttpResponse("<html><body bgcolor = cyan> Thanks For Feedback </body></html>")

index.html

<form action="./insert" method="get">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name" name="NAME">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address" name = "EMAIL">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="3"  placeholder="Message" name = "MSG" ></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Request</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>

urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/$',index_page),
    url(r'^insert/$',views.insert_page,name = 'insert'),

]
```

Answer (score 1):

I reckon the method is supposed to be `POST` here. But if you want to try `GET` on dev - it's ok.

```
<form action="./insert" method="get">
```

and the URL must be `"/insert"`

```
<form action="/insert" method="post">
```

starting with `/` means - under the root page, starting with `./` means - under current page's URL.

If this is what you want then you must handle `url(r'^home/insert/', ...` instead of `url('^insert/')`. If not - fix URL in form's `action` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed `views.index_page` for url(r'^home/$',index_page),